Simulating the Howland Current Pump in Real-World Applications
I am working on developing a device that has to deliver a bipolar sinusoidal current with zero offset through a variable load (from 1k to 10k Ohm), with a maximum peak current of 4mA. This means, that the current through the load will be at max a bipolar sinusoidal signal between -4mA and 4mA.
I have designed the following circuit, where the current through the load (R17) is does not depend on its value (Iout=Vsin/R), where R corresponds to each of the four 625 Ohms resistors I'm using to obtain a 4mA peak sinusoidal current, bearing in mind the power supply constraints of the op-amp.

In KiCad simulation software, using an ideal SPICE model for the op amp (it considers that the op amp has infinitive gain and infinitive power supply), the current through R17 is the expected and the input voltages at the inverting and non-inverting inputs of the op amp are equal.
However, when I replace the ideal SPICE model with a real op-amp SPICE model, specifically the AD8510 (which has a max power supply of +-15V), the performance is not as expected.
These are the results I obtain from the simulations:

Current through R17 (it is a sinusoidal between 2.55mA and 2mA, and it should be between -4mA and 4mA):


Input inverting (green) and non-inverting (purple) voltages op-amp should be equal but they are not:



Could you help me solving this problem? I've been designing different circuits based on the Howland current pump circuit and all of them work well when using ideal op-amp SPICE models for the simulations but they don't work as expected when I replace them with real op-amp SPICE models.

You are up against bandwidth or slew-rate limits, probably, which is the biggest reason inverting and non-inverting input potentials would differ. There are other op-amp non-idealities which can contribute, but start by reducing frequency to see if the input potential difference is reduced.

Step 1: Check the output voltage swing on your ideal opamp with your circuit. What did you get there? Is it within the rails you provided your opamp in the non-ideal case? Step 2: Did you do the math? What's the transfer function from your source to your load (R17?) The reason I ask is that the values I get for the output to achieve 4 mA aren't possible with your rails and your specified load in the non-ideal case.

Your V9 voltage source appears to be backwards. You flipped it (to invert) and then set it to "-15" (invert again, one could say).   The result seems that you are giving your opamp +15V to both terminals.
This is notwithstanding the other answers about having adequate headroom.

That's true! I inverted it and now the simulation is working well. Thank you so much

Here's the first problem. A peak current of 4 mA through 10 kΩ is a peak voltage of 40 volts. But, it's worse than that because you want +/- 4 mA so, that means a signal level across the 10 kΩ resistor of 80 volts p-p.
You'll never get that with a total supply voltage of 30 volts.
Then you have to consider the voltage dropped across the 625 Ω resistor at 4 mA. That's another 5 volts p-p added to your overhead. Then if you use conventional op-amps that have a maximum swing limited to (say) 4 volts inside the power rails, you really are up against it.
In short, to meet your full requirements you'll need a total supply voltage of about 90 volts and, an op-amp that can work with these supply levels.
Even with a 3 kΩ load the supply would need to be based on all these: -

3 kΩ x +/-4 mA means a voltage across the load of 24 volts p-p
You need another 5 volts p-p because of R15
You'll need maybe another 4 volts due to op-amp imperfections.

That's a total supply of 33 volts.
Next is consideration of the current that flows from the op-amp output through R13 and R14. Both are 625 Ω making a total load of 1250 Ω. That "load" connects (in effect) to ground so, if the peak voltage produced by your op-amps is (say) +14.5 volts, the current through R13 and R14 is going to be 11.6 mA. That's more current that what you are trying to control and, massively and significantly, it eats into what any reasonable op-amp can deliver at its output.

However, when I replace the ideal SPICE model with a real op-amp SPICE model, specifically the AD8510 (which has a max power supply of
+-15V), the performance is not as expected.

The AD8510 is slightly worse than my assumptions above: -

Across temperature the maximum positive guaranteed output voltage on a 600 Ω load (near enough to your situation) may only be +11.4 volts
Across temperature the maximum negative guaranteed output voltage on a 600 Ω load (near enough to your situation) may only be -12.1 volts
And, given your design I would expect it to get quite warm


Thank  you so much for your answer!

@NeusPonsAndrés that's good. Maybe you should consider accepting an answer that works best for you: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

If you perform the following:
eqplus = Eq( vp/r16 + vp/r15 + vp/r17, vin/r16 + vout/r15 )    # (+) KCL
eqminus = Eq( vm/r13 + vm/r14, vout/r14 )                      # (-) KCL
eqout = Eq( vout/r15 + vout/r14, vm/r14 + vp/r15 + iout )      # output KCL
eqassume = Eq( vm, vp )                                        # if things work
ans = solve( [ eqplus, eqminus, eqout, eqassume ], [ iout, vp, vm, vout] )
ans[vout].subs({r13:625,r14:625,r15:625,r16:625,r17:3e3,vin:-2.5})
-24
ans[vout].subs({r13:625,r14:625,r15:625,r16:625,r17:3e3,vin:2.5})
24
ans[vp].subs({r13:625,r14:625,r15:625,r16:625,r17:3e3,vin:-2.5})
-12
ans[vp].subs({r13:625,r14:625,r15:625,r16:625,r17:3e3,vin:2.5})
12

So you can see that you should get \$\pm 4\:\text{mA}=\frac{\pm 12\:\text{V}}{3\:\text{k}\Omega}\$. That is, if and only if, the opamp can provide \$\pm 24\:\text{V}\$ at its output. It can't. And that's why you are getting the behavior you see with a more realistic opamp model, in play, and when using rails that are insufficient for the job.
Also note:
ans[iout].subs({r13:625,r14:625,r15:625,r16:625,r17:3e3,vin:-2.5})
-0.0384
ans[iout].subs({r13:625,r14:625,r15:625,r16:625,r17:3e3,vin:2.5})
0.0384

So make sure your non-ideal opamp is capable of at least that output current compliance, \$\pm38.4\:\text{mA}\$, while also providing the indicated output voltage needed. If the output impedance for the opamp is, say, \$100\:\Omega\$, then this means rails of at least \$\pm 28\:\text{V}\$, if not more.
One option might be to use external parts to supplement your opamp. There are several options available there, some more and some less obvious.

Thank you so much for your answer

@NeusPonsAndrés Hope it helps. Thanks very much for letting me know it may have helped some. It's nice to hear from you.

As already pointed out other answers, Supply voltages are insufficient. ...
With the use of another opamp like OP454 (+/- 50 V), it should be ok.
Note: not completely wired on the schematic
Made with microcap v12


Thanks! that's a good op-amp option for my application
